# Suitable color space preset for reducing eye strain in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, unity, gnome, colors, color-management

I'd like to change my color profile permanently to something that reduces blue light as much as possible to reduce eye strain, but I don't know what each of the preset color profiles in the `Color` settings do. Is there somewhere that I can get an explanation of each profile, or can someone recommend a suitable profile.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.3 with the default desktop environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use an application named [Redshift](http://jonls.dk/redshift/) for this purpose. You can install it by running the following command in Terminal

```
sudo apt-get install redshift redshift-gtk
```